# Parse and store text from a json file in windows batch script

Tags: json, batch-file

I have a json file with the following contents

```
{"STATUS":"PASS","PASSRATE":96.95238}
```

I want to store the passrate so that I can use it to append to a filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [jsonextractor.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat) with which you can extract information from json file by given dot notated path to object:

```
jsonextractor.bat data.json PASSRATE
```

Comment: Smooth! Thanks! You are making a html out of it and parsing using javascript I suppose.

Comment: @RakeshHorkeri - it is only jscript and html activex object which allows me to use ecmascript6 methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) for that:

```
xidel -s data.json -e "$json/PASSRATE"
```